# ng-repeat takes a lot time to render html?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angular-ui

repeat which has data around 4k +. it takes a lot time to render html.

I am getting data from backend in 3 sec and ng-repeat takes around 9 secs to render all the 4k + records.

Is there any way I can speed up the performance of ng-repeat?

Thanks for your help?

Comment: It would help if you'd provide the code that renders your page, it's hard to guess without knowing what's going on in your code.

Comment: yes,clean up your models so they only have the data you are going to display.Dont just fetch your records and display them,filter the data that is relevant to the view.And paginating data helps too.I cant think of any use case when you'd absolutely have to display 4000 lines of data in the same page.

Comment: what if I add limitTo filter. In that case should it wait for all the 400 records to render or the value I am passing to limitTo filter?

Answer (score 3):

If you have elements which get recreated but could be duplicates you may want to look at the `track by` feature added in Angular 1.2. It will speed up `ngRepeat` noticeably, in particular on mobile devices.

[Improving ngRepeat performance with track by](http://www.codelord.net/2014/04/15/improving-ng-repeat-performance-with-track-by/)

In addition you can exploit [limitTo](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/limitTo), which adjustes the number of rendered elements. A detailed explanation of this approach can be found here:

[My solution to the ngRepeat performance problem](http://www.williambrownstreet.net/blog/2013/07/angularjs-my-solution-to-the-ng-repeat-performance-problem/)

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried this? http://tech.small-improvements.com/2013/09/10/angularjs-performance-with-large-lists/

You can also try lazy loading the records at the bottom of the list or soft pagination in order to delay the rendering of all 4k records at once. Although it's more of a UX treatment.

I used this to soft paginate a table of 20k records,

```
<div ng-repeat="item in list | limitTo:n></div>
<a href="javascript:void(0)" ng-click="n=n+100">more</a>
```

Comment: I already did this still I am not sure why it is taking 9 secs. Is there any way that i can check where it is taking time?

Comment: You can use [Batarang](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/angularjs-batarang/ighdmehidhipcmcojjgiloacoafjmpfk?hl=en) to monitor that. If you have functions or filters used in ng-bindgins, try to memoize them. That should help reduce the run time expression evaluation and give you some speed.